# Arrays as address constants in functions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm teaching myself C++ and had some questions about arrays and pointers.  My understanding is that arrays are really just pointers, however, arrays are **address constants** which cannot be changed.

If this is the case, I was wondering why in my function `show2()` I was able to change the address of the pointer `list`.  Unlike variables, I thought arrays are passed by reference so I was expecting a compiler error when calling function `show2()` since I incremented the address of `list`.  But the code works just fine.  Can someone please explain?

Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void show1(double *list, int SIZE)
{
    for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << *(list+i);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

void show2(double *list, int SIZE)
{
    double *ptr = list;

    for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << setw(5) << *list++;
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    double rates[] = {6.5, 7.2, 7.5,  8.3, 8.6, 
                      9.4, 9.6, 9.8, 10.0};
    const int SIZE = sizeof(rates) / sizeof(double);

    show1(rates, SIZE);
    show2(rates, SIZE);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that arrays are really just pointers

Let's get that out of the way.  No, arrays are not pointers.  Arrays are a series of objects, all of the same type, contiguous in memory.

Arrays *can* be passed by reference, but that is not what is usually done.  What is usually done, which is what you are doing, is passing a pointer to the first element of the array.  Arrays can and will "decay" to a pointer to their first element upon demand.  And that's what is happening when you pass `rates` to `show1` and `show2`.

Inside `show1` and `show2`, `list` starts out as a pointer to `rates[0]`.  You're free to modify this pointer to point at any other `double`.

If you wanted to pass an array by reference, it would look like this:

```
void show3(double (&list)[9]) { ... }
```

Or the more versatile:

```
template<size_t SIZE>
void show3(double (&list)[SIZE]) { ... }
```

Note that what you *can't* do is pass an array by value (unless it is contained within another object).  If you write a function which looks like it is taking an array by value, e.g.

```
void show4(double list[9]) { ... }
```

It is actually a pointer, and that number 9 is meaningless.  Native arrays suck.

Answer (score 1):

First, arrays are converted to a pointer to the first element when passed as the function argument. BTW, arrays are not pointers, as one example, `sizeof(rates)` in your code isn't the size of a pointer.

Second, arrays are passed by value since you are not using references.

So in the function `show2`, you are modifying a pointer, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not pointers. C++ has inherited "[Array-Pointer Equivalence](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)" from C which means that a well-known array variable can *decay* to a pointer, primarily for the purpose of offset math and for avoiding passing arrays by value:

```
int array[64];
int* a = array; // equivalent to a = &array[0];
```

Array's aren't pointers. If you use an array variable name in a pointer context, it will "decay" to a pointer - that is, lose the extended attributes available from an array object.

```
int array[64];
int* a = array;
std::cout << "array size = " << sizeof(array) << "\n";
std::cout <<  "a size = " << sizeof(a) << "\n";
std::cout << "(int*)(array) size = " << sizeof((int*)array)) << "\n";
```

"Array size" will be 256 (int is 4 bytes, 64 of them = 256 bytes), "a size" will be 4 or 8 bytes depending on 32/64 bits, and "(int*)(array)" size will be the same size as the pointer.

People often think that arrays are passed by value. This is not true: http://ideone.com/hAeH18

```
#include <iostream>

void bump(int arr[3]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        arr[i]++;
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    bump(array);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << array[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs "2, 3, 4" not "1, 2, 3".

This occurs because arrays decay to pointers when passed as function arguments. But to support the syntax for receiving arrays as arrays, C has to be able to treat pointers like arrays in some contexts:

```
void f1(int* a) { a[0]++; }

void f2(int* a) { (*a)++; }

void f3(int a[]) { a[0]++; }

void f4(int a[]) { (*a)++; }

void f5(int a[1]) { a[0]++; }

void f6(int a[1]) { (*a)++; }
```

All of these functions produce the same code.

In C, this originated from the fact that array information is lost at compile time. So this function:

```
void f(int array[])
```

has no way to tell how large the array it is receiving is. They wanted programmers to be conscious of this and be careful about how/if they passed size information - e.g. in the case of char arrays, instead of size, we have the nul terminator byte.

Unfortunately they didn't choose to make it obvious by diasllowing the representation that makes it look like you are receiving an array with size information intact :(